# Strange error from timer job service

Tags: timer-jobs

I'm developing timer job for SharePoint 2010. I was able to deploy it on my local machine but when I was trying to execute timer job I get strange error message:

```
Job definition SP2010.CopyDocsJob, id 7a0e9bbe-90f1-441f-8e8a-3b918b440436 has no online instance for service SP2010.Features.CopyDocsTimerJob.CopyDocsTimerJobEventReceiver+JobService, id 67649b18-5a00-4420-84fb-cfe7bf90ceeb, ignoring
```

How to fix this issue? How to make this timer job works?

PS: After deploy I have restarted SP Timer Job service so assembly has been loaded into system.

Comment: Please Post your code, Have you created proper instances for Timer Job ?

Comment: Would you please share your code.

Comment: How do you register the timer job? If it's associated with a web app, content DB? It could be that the associated resource is offline.

Comment: What is the scope of the timer job? Farm, web application or site?